# Determine if the sets of vectors are a basis for the indicated space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused on how to determine if the sets of vectors are a basis of the space:

$a) \{(5,2,-1), (1,0,1), (3,-1,0)\}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ , and

$b) \{1,0,,-2,5), (4,4,-3,2), (0,1,0,-3), (1,3,3,-10)\}$ in $\mathbb R^4$.

Attempt:

$a)$ I put each of the vectors into an equation as follows:

$$5a+b+3c=0
\\
2a-c=0
\\
-a+b=0$$

and found out that the equations above will only be true if $a=b=c=0,$ and therefore they are linearly independent.  I also found out that the matrix is invertible through calculating the determinant (which equals $12$), and therefore these sets of vectors are a basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

$b)$ I put each of the vectors into a matrix, and after RREF I found out that there are solutions to each of the vectors, but do not know how to carry on.

Am I doing something wrong in my work or am I giving a false conclusion?

Comment: a matrix is invertible iff the determinant is NOT zero.

Comment: Your two statements about a) are inconsistent. The system has a unique solution iff the matrix *is* invertible.

Comment: @peco  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first set of vectors the determinant is 6 (not 0) which indicates that the matrix is inversible, thus the vectors are linearly independent, and these 3 vectors FORM a base of $\mathbb R^3$.

For the set b, you can simply put the vectors in a 4x4 matrix and calculate the determinant, you will get 0 indicating that the vectors aren’t linearly independent and thus they can’t form a base of $\mathbb R^4$.

You can also proceed in the same manner of a, by setting the vectors in a system of 4 unknowns $(a,b,c,d)$ and solve it for $(0,0,0,0)$, you will definitely get an answer other than vector 0 indicating the dependence between these vectors.

Hope I helped.

Comment: so it means that if a matrix is invertible, then the vectors form a basis for the space and if a matrix is not invertible then the vectors aren't a basis for the space correct?

Comment: Long story short, yes.

Comment: ok i think i get it now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In both case the most efficent method is to arrange the vectors as rows in a matrix (note that it is not defined augmented) and [**obtain the RREF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) by elementary row operations.

From the number of pivots in the RREF we can find if the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: ok i get it thanks!

Comment: @peco Well done!

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, upon reaching the conclusion that $a=b=c=0$, you can conclude that it forms a basis. You have calculated the determinant wrongly, it should not be zero.

```
> det(matrix(c(5,2,-1,1,0,1,3,-1,0),nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
[1] 12
```

You should repeat the same procedure for the second question, if you can find a non-trivial solution, then it is linearly dependent and it is not a basis.  Alternatively, just compute the determinant and check if it is zero.(The second answer is not a basis).

Comment: ok great thanks!